# Hourly recurring Ballerina task executes immediately

Tags: ballerina

Created a task to run in an hour. The first run happens as soon as it is scheduled. Is it the expected behavior?

```php
service /registry on new http:Listener(common:servicePort) {
    function init() returns error? {
        //the job runs for the first time when the service is started, and then it runs periodically
        task:JobId saasApiLoadJobId = check 
                  task:scheduleJobRecurByFrequency(new SaaSAPILoader(0), common:saasApiReloadInterval);
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the start time. The start time of the trigger is in Ballerina time:Civil. If it is not provided, a trigger will start immediately.
Check the API documentation,
https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/task/2.5.0#scheduleJobRecurByFrequency

```
    // start first execution of the task in one hour from now.
    time:Utc startTime = time:utcAddSeconds(time:utcNow(), 3600);
    time:Civil startCivilTime = time:utcToCivil(startTime);
    task:JobId saasApiLoadJobId = check task:scheduleJobRecurByFrequency(new SaaSAPILoader(0), common:saasApiReloadInterva, startTime = startCivilTimel);
```